# Facebook Creating new apps from Developer Facebook always returns public_profile permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Recently,
I am creating new Facebook apps in https://developers.facebook.com. 
but unfortunately when i login and request publish permission it's always return "public_profile" for my permission;

here's my sample Code:
facebookButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_default);
facebookButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions","publish_stresm"));

and after the session if OPENED:
i try to call;

Session.getactiveSession().getpermission -> always return "public_profile";

How can i set mu publish permission?
Thx 4 advice.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`publish_stream` is deprecated, `publish_actions` covers everything you need.

You are probably trying it with a random user without a role in the dev settings of the App. Most permissions need to go through a review process now, in order to make them work for other users.

Take a look at the changelog and the review guidelines for more information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review